# SQLite3: no such column: "id desc"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I'm working on a piece of very old code (ruby 1.9.3 and rails 2.3.12). I'm trying to write some tests for it so that when I start upgrading it I have an idea of how everything is working. I'm writing them in cucumber at the moment and have come across an issue that I can't seem to solve. This issue does not appear in the production version as everything works fine on that. In the development AND test however, when I try and click one of the links, the following error appears;

```
And I click "Trips (1)"         # features/step_definitions/user_management_steps.rb:1
      SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: "id desc": SELECT "trips".* FROM "trips"  INNER JOIN "trips_users" ON "trips".id = "trips_users".trip_id    WHERE (("trips_users".user_id = 1))  ORDER BY ["id desc"] LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0 (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
      ./vendor/plugins/geokit-rails/lib/geokit-rails/acts_as_mappable.rb:157:in `find'
      ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:259:in `trips'
      /home/camillavk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'
      <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
      ./features/step_definitions/user_management_steps.rb:2:in `/^I click "([^"]*)"$/'
      features/trips.feature:30:in `And I click "Trips (1)"'
```

I've looked everywhere and cannot find any reference to

```
no such column: "id desc"
```

does anyone know what this means?

And why does this break in the development and test environments but not in the production environment?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

*Edit

gemfile;

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem "rails", "~> 2.3.12"

gem "airbrake"
gem "aws-s3"
gem "bj"
gem "calendar_date_select", "1.15"
gem "cancan", "1.2.0"
gem "carmen"
gem 'comma', '0.4.1'
gem 'exifr'
gem "factory_girl", "1.2.4"
gem 'fastercsv'
gem "geokit"
gem "haml"
gem "hpricot"
gem 'hoptoad_notifier'
gem "jrails"
gem "libxml-ruby", "2.4.0"
gem "memcached", "~> 1.8.0"
gem "mysql2", "~> 0.2.6"
gem "rake", "0.8.3"
gem 'recurly'
gem "rdoc"
gem "rmagick"
gem "rspreedly"
gem "rubyzip"
gem 'sass'
#need to use simplecov when upgrading to ruby 2 as rcov doesn't work
gem "simplecov"
gem 'sqlite3'
gem "will_paginate", "2.3.16"
gem 'yaml_db'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'test-unit', '1.2.3'
  gem 'rspec', '1.3.2'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 1.3.4'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '0.3.5'
  gem 'cucumber', '1.1.2'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', :git => "git://github.com/RKelln/cucumber-rails.git", :branch => "0.3.2-capybara-fix"
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end
```

user_controller.rb;

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :find_user
  load_and_authorize_resource :except => [:news, :search, :update, :mobile_new, :mobile_success]
  before_filter :authorise, :only => [:export_to_csv]

  def find_user
    begin
      @user = User.find_by_login(params[:id])
    rescue
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end
  end

....
....
def trips
    body_attributes "view-followers", 'main-feed', 'Trips'

    @page = (params[:page].to_i || 0)
    @page = 1 if @page == 0
    @trips = @user.trips.reverse_order

    @year = ''
    @month = ''

    unless params[:year].blank?
      @year = params[:year].to_i
      @trips = @trips.select { |trip| trip.start_date.year == @year }
    end

    unless params[:month].blank?
      @month = params[:month].to_i
      @trips = @trips.select { |trip| trip.start_date.month == @month }
    end

    @years = Array.new
    unless @user.trips.empty?
      @years = @user.trips.first.start_date.year..@user.trips.last.start_date.year
    end

    @show_more_link = @trips.count > (10 * @page)
    @trips = @trips.paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => @page)
  end
```

Comment: Show your `user_controller.rb` file.

Comment: Your `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` could help too (if there are any). Maybe the SQLite3 gem has introduced breaking changes since the app was made.

Comment: I've added user_controller and gemfile to the question now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have an order on your Trips query defined like this `Trip.order('[id desc]')`. The correct format is (depending on your Rails version):

```
Trip.order('id DESC') 
Trip.order(id: :desc) # works only in Rails >= 4.0
```

Comment: I've looked everywhere in the code and can't seem to find anywhere there is a Trips query defined like that....where would this possibly be?

Comment: Actually, you were correct...I kept searching and found in trips.rb a line with Trip.order(' [id desc] ') as you said. I removed the square brackets and it now works... thanks! :-)